# Laravel ordering current to end date

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I `orderBy` date in laravel/mysql only if the `current date` is within/between `starts_at` and `ends_at` dates?

For example:

```
// Suppose Current Date: 2018-10-05

- Example A
  = Starts At: NULL,       Ends At: NULL,       Created At: 2018-10-05
- Example B
  = Starts At: NULL,       Ends At: NULL,       Created At: 2018-10-04
- Example C
  = Starts At: 2018-10-01, Ends At: 2018-10-03, Created At: 2018-10-03
- Example D
  = Starts At: 2018-10-03, Ends At: 2018-10-05, Created At: 2018-10-02
- Example E
  = Starts At: 2018-10-05, Ends At: 2018-10-07, Created At: 2018-10-01
- Example F
  = Starts At: 2018-10-07, Ends At: 2018-10-09, Created At: 2018-09-30
```

My current query is (column are `starts_at` and `ends_at`):

```
Example::orderByRaw('if(isnull(starts_at) >= curdate() and isnull(ends_at) <= curdate(), starts_at, created_at) desc');
```

Resulting to:

```
- Example A
- Example B
- Example C
- Example D
- Example E
- Example F
```

Expected result:

```
- Example E // First because of starts at 2018-10-05 until 2018-10-07
- Example A --
- Example B   |_ // Same order based expired/null
- Example C   |
- Example D --
- Example F // Still last because starts at is in the future
```

Here is  my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7b3b2).

Comment: Why is `E` first? Because it starts "today"?

Comment: Yes and others are either null, expired or future date.

Comment: What if `start_date` is yesterday and `end_date` is today/tomorrow?

Comment: If `E`'s `starts_at` is yesterday and `ends_at` is today, `E` will be considered as `expired`. If `E`'s `ends_at` is tomorrow then `E` will be first on the list. Incase 2 or more are same with `E`, they will be on top ordered by it's created at.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Example::orderBy('ends_at','desc')->latest()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This query would greatly benefit from Laravel's quite phenomenal [Query Buider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses).

Try this:

```
Example::where([
    ['ends_at', '>=', Carbon::now()],
    ['starts_at', '<=', Carbon::now()],
    ['ends_at', '!=', null],
    ['starts_at', '!=', null]
])
->orderBy('ends_at','desc')
->get();
```

This should get you close to what you want.  Depending on your table's column type, you may have to modify the format of the `Carbon` objects slightly so that the comparison doesn't throw an error.

ie.

```
Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') // 2018-10-04
```

It also ensures that rows where `ends_at` and `starts_at` equal `null` are not shown.  Finally, orders newest to oldest.

Hope this helps!